# Can additional custom behavior be added to all methods of a python class

Tags: python

I would like to add some additional behavior to all methods in a Python class without having to define this in each method.

For example, timing every function.

```py
class A:
    def a(self):
        print('a')

    def b(self):
        print('b')
```

Is there any way to modify the behavior of each method when called from an instance of class `A` without needing to define this in every method (preferably without the use of decorators):

```py
class A:
    def a(self):
        s = time.time()
        print('a')
        e = time.time()
        print(f'a: {e - s}s')

    def b(self):
        s = time.time()
        print('b')
        e = time.time()
        print(f'b: {e - s}s')
```

Comment: It could be done with a metaclass. But, personally, I think it is a reasonable use-case for a decorator.